# Direct product of permutation groups (just notation)

Tags: group-theory, permutations, notation

If I have two permutations groups over independent elements, let's say

$S_2=\{\,(1)(2) \,, (12)\,\}\,$ and $\,S_2'=\{\,(3)(4) \,, (34)\,\}$

Is it OK to denote the set $\{\,(1)(2)(3)(4) \,, (12)(3)(4) \,, (1)(2)(34) \,, (12)(34)\,\}$ as $S_2^2$ ?.

Or... maybe.... is it better to denote it as $S_2\times S_2'$?

Thanks.

Comment: $S_2\times S_2’$ looks like product (ordered pairs).  How about $\langle S_2, S_2’\rangle$?

Comment: I'd go for $S_2S_2'$.

Comment: What does $(1)(2)$ means?

Comment: Does $(1)(2)$ mean $1\mapsto1$ and $2\mapsto2$ (identity)?

Comment: yes, $(x)$ is just the identity $x\mapsto x$.